# What does "walk for a wager" mean in "A Fisher of Men"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, r-austin-freeman, dr-thorndyke

In "[A Fisher of Men](https://archive.org/details/bluescarab00free/page/162/mode/2up)" in *Dr. Thorndyke's Case-Book* by R. Austin Freeman, Dr. Jervis was digging the earth with his friend, while they saw a stranger man coming along the path, then that man was for the moment hidden from them by a bend of the path and a near clump of bushes.

> At this moment the stranger reappeared, **walking as if for a wager**, and I began to peck up the earth with my pocket-knife.

I searched for its meaning, but I didn't find anything that I can understand in this context!

- [wager (in Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/wager),
- [1819 Play Bills From The Theatre Royal](http://susannaives.com/wordpress/2014/03/1819-play-bills-from-the-theatre-royal/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Competitive walking, known as ‘pedestrianism’, was the forerunner of today’s walking races.
Per [Wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedestrianism):

> Pedestrianism was a 19th-century form of competitive walking, often professional and funded by wagering, from which the modern sport of racewalking developed.

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense. So he was walking as if in competitve walking that some people bet on it? @Spagirl

Comment: That is correct.